# How to convert a gradle based java app to maven app?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle based java application designed based out of Netflix OSS. I want to convert the app to maven based.
Can anyone please help me to convert the app ?

Answer (score 1):

It should fairly easy to achieve the same.

1. Maven and Gradle have a similar concept of dependency management.
2. The compilation and other stuff is similar.
3. Only thing which varies is customizability which gradle provides.

Following link should get you started:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_pom_generation